# how to set value of color input on null

Tags: javascript, html, css, selector

Hi I have a color input and I want to store it in my database on null but it has default value black color
how can I change it to null? 
I removed value att but it has still default value

```
    <input class="form-control h-50px" type="color" id="example-color-input" name="color_2">
```

Comment: There is no way to do that. It always has to have some color defined.

Comment: One option might be to add the disabled attribute to the input when there is no value. Disabled inputs are not submitted to the server, so it should appear null on the server side. With this approach, however, you will need to have logic to enable / disable the input so that the user can still pick (or blank out) the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `data-*` attribute to your input with no value, then update it when the value of your input has been changed at least once.

In my snippet, the real value is set as soon as the input is clicked (so if you click it without change the color at the end, it will return you `#000000`). Remove this behavior by removing the `click` event.

The button is just logging the value of the input.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // INPUT
  const eInput = document.querySelector('input'),
    inputEvent =  () => eInput.dataset.realValue = eInput.value;
  
  eInput.addEventListener('click', inputEvent);
  eInput.addEventListener('change', inputEvent);
  
  // LOG BTN
  const eBtn = document.querySelector('button');
  
  eBtn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(getColorInputValue(eInput)));
});

/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 * @returns {string|null}
 */
function getColorInputValue(element) {
  return element.dataset.realValue;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" data-real-value="">

<button>Get color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add defaultValue  attribute.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_color_defaultvalue.asp